# HTML - передача параметра

Tags: html, css

Являюсь начинающим в html и css, сразу извиняюсь за некорректный вопрос, не знаю как его правильно задать. Вопрос такой - возможно ли в этом случае сделать передачу параметра и можно ли это все обернуть в форму с методом post?   Нужен именно такой вид кнопки , не знаю как этого добиться используя `input type = submit;`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="student.html" class="editstudentdiv">Name Surname</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Интересует, можно ли в таблицу засунуть форму?

Comment: `<form>` вокруг таблицы, `<input>`ы внутри `<td>`?

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы при нажатии на submit в форме сработал метод POST и при этом открылась страница student.html ?